# httpwebrequest getresponse() does not return any content whereas fiddler shows content

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I created the `GetCourses()` method where I am using `HttpWebRequest` to request data from the Url shown.  If I copy paste the url in a browser, the browser will show xml data.  I also used fiddler to do the some request.  On fiddler it says that the data is encoded and i have to decode it. So, I clicked on the decode and I can see the XML. However, using the code below I get back Content-Length=-1.

```
public static void GetCourses()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest requestForItCourse =
               (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mnsu.edu/schedule/direct.php?action=courses&term=20135&subject=it");
            requestForItCourse.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip|DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
            HttpWebResponse responseFromMnsuDirectPhp =
                (HttpWebResponse)requestForItCourse.GetResponse();

            Stream dataStream = responseFromMnsuDirectPhp.GetResponseStream();
            responseFromMnsuDirectPhp.Close();
//Parse and insert courses into the database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you close the response and THEN read the stream? That does not make any sense. When you close your response, you also make the underlying data unavailable.

Comment: make sure your reading the stream before you close the response, if you are, then make sure you send a user agent and a referrer header, some sites are coded to detect scrapers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked when I ran it. You need to read the stream before closing it. As a side note, many people prefer to have their Streams automatically closed by using the `using` keyword.

```
try
{
    HttpWebRequest requestForItCourse = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mnsu.edu/schedule/direct.php?action=courses&term=20135&subject=it");
    requestForItCourse.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
    HttpWebResponse responseFromMnsuDirectPhp =
                (HttpWebResponse)requestForItCourse.GetResponse();

    string raw_xml;
    using(var sr = new StreamReader(responseFromMnsuDirectPhp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        raw_xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    //Parse and insert courses into the database
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need read the response stream before close the response.

Try this:

```
HttpWebRequest requestForItCourse = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.mnsu.edu/schedule/direct.php?action=courses&term=20135&subject=it");
requestForItCourse.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
HttpWebResponse responseFromMnsuDirectPhp = (HttpWebResponse)requestForItCourse.GetResponse();

StreamReader dataStream = new StreamReader(responseFromMnsuDirectPhp.GetResponseStream());
string data = dataStream.ReadToEnd();

responseFromMnsuDirectPhp.Close();
dataStream.Close();
```